# How can I get an iframe to open a site saved in a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an iframe browser program; it's pretty basic. I was going to add a bookmark feature where a prompt popped up and saved the site they wanted as a bookmark to a variable.  I then realized I don't know how to make an iframe open a site saved in a variable. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the source of an iframe using the `attr()` method if you have an iframe.

```
$('#myframe').attr('src', 'http://example.org/')
```

If you don't have an iframe, you can append a new iframe to your page.

```
$('#mysection').append("<iframe id='myframe'>")
```